# How to have overflow scroll only in one axis but visibility and no scroll in the other

Tags: css, overflow

I have researched this but could only find very old answers and no real solution. This is the problem:

```css
div {position: absolute;width:300px;height:250px;background:black;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:visible;}
span {display:block;position:relative;background:red;width:300px;height:530px;}
button {position: absolute;width:100px;height:50px;background:blue;left:250px;}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>
  <button>
  </button>
 </span>
</div>
```

the blue rectangle should stick out of the main div without the need of a scrollbar, whereas the red rectangle should be scrollable in the y axis. But it seems like I cant have a scrollbar only in one axis. Is there a workaround for this? CSS only please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/10051059

Comment: that answer is over 10 years old...

Comment: Answer provides an [overflow test page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html). You can see the rules still apply the same in your modern browser.

Comment: it means there is no solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a way around with only CSS, and without changing the markup.

You can set the `div`'s width bigger to include the blue `button`.

Then you can make the `scrollbar` closer to the `div`, as if the `div` is smaller.

You can't use `margin` and `padding` on `scrollbar`. So you have to make it `transparent` and cast a `shadow` on it to make it look like it's next to the `div`.

You can use this component with other components by using `position: absolute` and `z-index` css-tricks

But honestly, it's a lot of work. It could be easier for you to go on another way.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width:400px;
  height:250px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:visible;
}
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: -90px 0px 0px 0px lightgrey;
    border: solid 3px transparent;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    box-shadow: -90px 0px 0px 0px grey;
    border: solid 3px transparent;
}
span {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  width:300px;
  height:530px;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  left:250px;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>
  <button>
  </button>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one more element as a holder. With an element that has scrolling enabled, no element can stick out to the side.

also, you should use a div instead of making a span a block element, since span tags should be used to mark up individual words as inline-block element inside div tags.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  background:black;
}

div.scroll {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:black;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

div.content {
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:530px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  top: 0;
  right:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but the problem is that the main div is position absolute and that the blue rectangle has to be attached to the span.

Comment: the main div could have position absolute. i changed it in my example. but i think the blue rectangle can not be inside the span (or div.content), while this is scrollable AND stick out.

changing the markup is not possible?

Comment: not quite. The button has to be attached to the span so it scrolls along with it. This is another example:  https://jsfiddle.net/zg198aqu/ it would be nice if only that yellow box could stick out.

Comment: okay, i get it wrong in the first place. so the box should scroll along and stick out on the left side of the element, but not be visible at the top and bottom outside the element?
but you can not mix "overflow-y: auto;" and "overflow-x: visible;" in one element.

Comment: so it seems but I need to achieve the effect. There must be a way around somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you put an extra `div` outside and move the `button` out of the scrollable area:

```css
#container{position: relative;}
#scrollable {position: absolute;width: 300px;height: 250px;background: black;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;}
#red {display: block;position: relative;background: red;width: 300px;height: 530px;}
button {position: absolute;width: 100px;height: 50px;background: blue;left: 250px;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="scrollable">
        <span id="red"></span>
    </div>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but the button has to scroll along with the red box as well.